# How do I create a unique list of dates in a drop down in ASP MVC with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with the Entity framework in ASP MVC and I want to pull a list of unique dates from the database that has a datetime field and display them in a drop down. I can't find a way to format the output and only list the unique dates in order so whomever is on the page will see something like "8/7/2015", "8/8/2015" instead of "8/7/2015 11:00:00 AM" and "8/7/2015 11:25:00 AM"... for `AppointmentStartDateTime`.

Here's my Model so far

```
public class Appointment
{
    [Key]
    [Column("apt_Id")]
    [Display(Name = "Appointment Id")]
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }

    [Column("apt_apl_Id")]
    public int AppealId { get; set; }
    public virtual Appeal Appeal { get; set; }

    [Column("apt_ofh_Id")]
    public int OfficeHoursId { get; set; }
    public virtual OfficeHours OfficeHours { get; set; }

    [Column("apt_StartDateTime")]
    public DateTime AppointmentStartDateTime { get; set; }
    [Column("apt_EndDateTime")]
    public DateTime AppointmentEndDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I'm stuck in the controller in the code shown below:

```
SelectList AppointmentDateSelectList = new SelectList(
    db.Appointment.Where(g => g.AppointmentStartDateTime > DateTime.Now),
    "AppointmentStartDateTime","AppointmentStartDateTime")
    .Select(a => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = Convert.ToDateTime(a.Text).ToShortDateString(),
        Value = a.Value
    });
```

I'm hoping someone knows how to make unique date list out of the start times.  I haven't found any information on it and I feel like I'm banging my head against a wall.

Comment: replace `ToShortDateString()` with `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")`

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You seem to be asking several questions.

Comment: Yes he asks 2 seperated questions I guess. But I dont know if he cares about answer.

Comment: I am asking how to make a drop down out of the second piece of code that has a unique list of Dates as the key and the Value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, and a tad off-topic, but I would encourage you to use good formatting. You'd be amazed at how often weird formatting makes a piece of code seem more complicated that it is. For this reason, I would also break out the database bit into a separate variable for readability.

```
var matchingAppointments = db.Appointment.Where(g => g.AppointmentStartDateTime > DateTime.Now);
```

Secondly, I think it makes more sense to do the sorting and distinct-ifying against the database portion, not the `SelectList` itself:

```
// Renamed variable
var distinctAppointmentDates = db.Appointment.Where(appt => appt.AppointmentStartDateTime > DateTime.Now)
                                             .OrderBy(appt => appt.AppointmentStartDateTime)
                                             .ToList()  // Force query execution
                                             .Select(appt => appt.AppointmentStartDateTime.ToShortDateString())
                                             .Distinct();

SelectList AppointmentDateSelectList = new SelectList(distinctAppointmentDates);
```

Lastly, your use of `ToShortDateString` is fine so far as I can see. I'm not sure why others think that is the issue.

Comment: `ToShortDateString()` truncates the time. The question says he wants to display the time as well.

Comment: @Juventus18 the question states exactly the opposite.

Comment: That formatting does look good however I'm met with an error when I use it.   "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: You can add a `ToList` call as I've edited in above to force the query to execute and pull the data into your application. The `Select` shouldn't need to change then.

Comment: Just re-read the original bits of my comment. Since my last edit, whereas the ordering still occurs on the database, the distinct operation occurs within your application. This is a result of the forced query execution.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `ToShortDateString()`, use `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`, or whatever other format you want.

NOTE:  This would be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a list of selectlistitems then put that list in your selectlist

```
var list = db.Appointment.Where(g => g.AppointmentStartDateTime > DateTime.Now)
                         .select(s => new SelectListItem{
                                     Text = s.AppointmentStartDateTime.ToString("dd/mm/yy"), 
                                     Value = a.AppintmentStartDateTime   
                         });

var AppointmentDateSelectList  = new SelectList(list, "Text","Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

To choose unique dates you can use `GroupBy()` in your linq query. `ToString()` will also help you with date format.

```
var list = db.Appointment.Where(g => g.AppointmentStartDateTime >DateTime.Now).GroupBy(x=>x.AppointmentStartDateTime)
    .select(s => new SelectListItem
    {
         Text = s.Key.Value.ToString("dd/mm/yy"), 
         Value = s.Key.Value.ToString()
    });

var AppointmentDateSelectList  = new SelectList(list, "Text","Value");
```

Comment: You would have to include `Today` to zero-out the time component within your `GroupBy` to get distinct dates. Otherwise, the group would only collect those appointments that were exactly the same date/time.